# Why is "Rank_Eq" breaking my loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a procedure which involves ranking values. My code (stripped down to important parts) looks like this:

```
Dim myArray() as variant
ReDim myArray(1 to 4, 1 to x)

for i = 1 to x
  myArray(1,i) = a
  myArray(2,i) = b
  myArray(3,i) = c
next i

for j = 1 to x
  myArray(4,j) = Application.Rank_Eq(myArray(3,j), Application.Index(myArray,3,0), 1)
next j

for k = 1 to x
  myFunction(myArray(4,k))
next k
```

Debugging it, the `for j = 1 to x` loop works fine if I just return, say, the value of `j` or the value of `myArray(3,j)` but it breaks out of the loop at j=1 when I use the `Application.Rank_Eq()` formula.

Have I done something really stupid that I just can't see, or is this an Excel issue?

EDIT:

I tried using the following to debug:

```
myIndex = Application.Index(myArray,3,0)

for k = 1 to x
  MsgBox myIndex(k,1)
  a = Application.Rank_Eq(myIndex(1,k), editedRows, 1)
next k
```

This appears to run ok - i.e. each value of `myIndex(k,1)` is returned. However, if I add `MsgBox a` before next `k`, then it breaks. This suggests it's something to do with the value being returned by `Rank_Eq`, no?

Comment: I would break that line into lines: `myVal = myArray(3,j)` and  `myIndex = Application.Index(myArray,3,0)` and `myArray(4,j) = Application.Rank_Eq(myVal, myIndex, 1)`. That way it is way easier to debug, where it is faililng.

Comment: @TorstenLink - see my edit. I still cannot understand what is causing the issue.

Comment: From research it looks like Rank_Eq doesn't accept an array in ref - it needs to be a reference...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not sure it's part of the issue - but I had to access the `Rank_Eq` method through the `WorksheetFunction` object, not the `Application` object.

Secondly, you'll notice that this function needs a `Double` and a `Range` for the first 2 arguments. Currently you are supplying a `Variant` and whatever the value is from your `Index()` method.

Try casting the `Variant` to a `Double` like so for the first argument:

```
CDbl(myArray(3, j))
```

For the second argument, I have no idea from your question how the array gets populated so I can't guess where the `Range` argument needs to refer to...